# How to implement functions with default parameters

Tags: java, function, optimization

In Java, I searched on the web how to make a function with defaults parameters, I learned that I need to write the function again, with less parameters.

Example:

```
f (a, b) {..}

f (a) {..}

f () {..}
```

Now, 2 ways to code those functions stand before me:

1. Copy-paste the algorithm in the 3 methods and modify it, replacing the parameters with the the constant values I need:

   ```
   f (a, b) { //algorithm with a and b }

   f (a) { //algorithm with a and a constant }

   f () { //algorithm with 2 constants }
   ```

   Advantage: running speed optimized

   Disadvantage: When I will need to make a modification in my function, I will have to change the code as many times I've written the function (here 3 three times).
2. Return the previous function by giving it the constants in parameters:

   ```
   f (a, b) { //algorithm }

   f (a) { return f (a, 1); }

   f () { return f ("x"); }
   ```

   Advantage: Easier to read, and the code is flexible.

   Disadvantage: When a function calls another function, it takes more running time and more memory (maybe I'm wrong about this point, and I would really like to be).

Which way is better?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not in English. (Traduisez votre question en anglais, s'il vous plait !)

Comment: This is not `French Stack Overflow`, please translate to English...

Comment: ok I will do it right now.

Comment: Have you had a play with the profiler (if you have a mainstream IDE it'll have one). It really helps to answer "which is faster" questions. and in this case would show the two methods are near identical for the considerable increase in horror of option 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you should prefer the second way. Duplicating code is really something you should avoid. It makes your code harder to maintain, and is the best way to introduce bugs. What you're doing here is a premature micro-optimization:

- it won't lead to any noticeable performance difference
- it will probably lead to no difference at all, because the JIT will inline the calls to the other methods in the second solution
- it could even be slower, because the JIT might not optimize one of the least-frequently used identical code blocks

Premature optimization is the root of all evil, and your question is another perfect example of that.

You shouldn't even think about optimizing code before you have a performance problem, and you have proven that the problem came for that code. 
Usually, performance problems come from IO (file reads, database queries, etc.), or from bad algorithms (O(n2) instead of O(n)) on large data sets. Not from 1 or 2 method calls.

Comment: If done extensively, it may also be slower since having more code means more cache pressure.